# print days of a special month ? laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to print only the records for the month of May

I get them with the variable

```
<td>{{ ($registro->created_at->format('d-m-Y')) }}</td>
```

I need to see only May results, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if condition

```
 @if($user->created_at->format('M')=="May")
        <td>{{ ($registro->created_at->format('d-m-Y')) }}</td>
    @endif
```

or

```
 @if($user->created_at->format('m')=="05")
        <td>{{ ($registro->created_at->format('d-m-Y')) }}</td>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check May month in created_at date

```
@if($user->created_at->format('m')=="05")
    <td>{{ ($registro->created_at->format('d-m-Y')) }}</td>
@endif
```